# different behaviors between Eigen::Ref and Eigen::MatrixBase

Tags: eigen

I am wondering why the following code generates a compile-time error:

```
void f(const double e) {}

void f(const Eigen::Ref<const MatrixX<double>>& g) {}

int main {
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> m1;
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> m2;
  m1 << 1.0, 2.0;
  m2 << 1.0, 2.0;
  f(m1.transpose() * m2);  // error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
}
```

while the following one doesn't.

```
void f(const double e) {}

template <typename Derived>
void f(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& m) {}

int main {
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> m1;
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> m2;
  m1 << 1.0, 2.0;
  m2 << 1.0, 2.0;
  f(m1.transpose() * m2);  // no error
}
```

Comment: FYI, in the second code snippet, `template <typename Derived> void f(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& m)` is called as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This because in your case `m1.transpose() * m2` is an inner product that is allowed to be assigned to a scalar:

```
double v = m1.transpose() * m2;
```

This is the unique situation where a `1x1` matrix expression is allowed to be converted to a scalar. In the second version there is no ambiguity because the type of the expression `m1.transpose() * m2` inherits `MatrixBase`.